# Calculating measurement covariance matrix for Kalman filter

Tags: bayesian, covariance, kalman-filter

I want to use a bayesian framework to correct the pose of a vehicle described by the following state vector
$$X=\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y\\
\theta
\end{bmatrix}$$

where $x$ and $y$ are the coordinates in the $XY$ plane and $\theta$ is the heading angle.

The measurement is acquired by a place recognition algorithm, where an online acquired image is compared to a set of database images and the best match is returned. Each image in the database is associated with a pose $(x,y,\theta)$ where this image has been acquired. 
So for any image, the algorithm will return an image from the database of index $1\leq j \leq N$, $N$ is the number of database images.
I want to associate a covariance matrix to the measurement (pose $(x_{j},y_{j},\theta_{j})$ associated to image $j$).

Could the covariance be calculated using the deviation matrix where we consider each pose associated to an image as an observation as follows

$$ Z = \begin{matrix}
 x     & y & \theta\\
 z_{1} 0.0052 & 0.7068 &  0.0104\\
 z_{2} 0.0052 & 0.7068 &  0.0104\\
 z_{3}0.7063 &  0.0050 & 0.0305\\
  \vdots &\vdots &\vdots\\
 z_{N}0.0113 &  0.0168 &  0.0002\\
\end{matrix}$$
or the covariance has to be in the following form?
$$ C = \begin{bmatrix}
 \sigma_{x}^2     & 0 & 0\\
 0 &  \sigma_{y}^2 &0\\
0 &0 & \sigma_{\theta}^2 
\end{bmatrix}$$